# How to swap the elements in a list if elements are same in python?

Tags: python

I have a issue. If I have list say ['a','b','c','a','b','c']. How do I place same values next to each other?

```
input: l = ['a','b','c','a','b','c']
excepted output: l =['a','a','b','b','c','c']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `sorted()` function on your list to get a [*lexicographically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) sorted new list:

```
>>> sorted(['a','b','c','a','b','c'])
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```

Refer [`sorted()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) for more details.

Comment: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable tried that got this error

Comment: Please post what you tried. You probably missed the second set of brackets

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)

```
l = ['a','b','c','a','b','c']
l.sort()
print(l)
# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

solution using sort is better but if you would like to see another one this also works

```
l = ['a','b','c','a','b','c']
ans = []
for x in set(l):
    ans.extend([x] * l.count(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two of the possibly many ways:

1. Use Counter (Linear Time Complexity, Linear Space Complexity)

```py
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(arr)
res = []
for k,v in c.items:
    res+=[k]*v
print(*res)
```

2. Use Sort (O(nlogn) Time Complexity, O(1) Space Complexity)

```py
arr.sort()
print(arr)
```